# Not receiving output even after writing printf("...")

Tags: c++

I've written a code to find the reciprocal of a number without using division but rather approximating it using bisection method. Got two doubts. One, what should I keep the lower limit and the upper limit for x? Also is there a faster method to converge from the limits to the required value(reciprocal of the input) rather than just averaging it? And the main doubt, when I try to run it, It just stops after receiving the input number from the user. Any hints so solve that?

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#define epsilon 0.0001
float f(float x, float &m)
{
    if(m==0)
    {
        printf("Reciprocal not defined");
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return x+1/m;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    float m,g1,x,g2,c;
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%f",f(x,m));
    g1=epsilon;
    g2=m;
    while(abs(f(g1,m)-f(g2,m))>epsilon)
    {
        c=(g1+g2)/2;
        if(f(g1,m)*f(c,m)<0)
        {
            g2=c;
        }
        else if(f(c,m)*f(g2,m)<0)
        {
            g1=c;
        }
    }
    printf("The reciprocal is approximately %f",c);

}
```

The code is expected to work as follows:

```
Enter a number: 5
The reciprocal is approximately 0.2
```

```
Enter a number: 0
Reciprocal is not defined
```

Instead of this, it shows:

```
Enter a number:
Reciprocal is not defined
```

(without accepting any input)

Comment: `scanf("%f",f(x,m));` will never work.

Comment: As mentioned above the scanf won't work but this should do    scanf("%f %f ",&m,&x);

Comment: What should I do instead of that? I only want the input value from the user to be stored in 'm' in f(x,m) and let 'x' be a free variable.

Comment: @SaumyaBhatt first you put it in a variable, and only then you pass that variable to `f`. How do you think `scanf` will know to put your input inside `m` instead of `x`?

Comment: Even without invalid syntax, `f` needs two (initialized) arguments to do anything meaningful. You are only reading one number. It looks like you have a misconception about how functions work...

Comment: [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) a demonstration on how to use the `scanf` function. Note that, as mentioned in the previous comment, the problem reside with your `scanf`.

Comment: Don't use printf and scanf. C++ has iostreams. [**Do not ignire compiler warnings**](https://rextester.com/QCVCE54867).

Comment: Unrelated to your problems with `scanf` you might face issues with delayed flushing your output. `stdout` is normally line buffered. It is not flushed unless you print a `'\n'`. This is missing in one of your prints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your overall code is far too convoluted and your usage of `scanf` doesn't make sens.

You probbaly want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

#define epsilon 0.0001f

int main(void)
{
  float m, g1, g2, c, diff;
  printf("Enter a number:\n");
  scanf("%f", &m);

  g1 = epsilon;
  g2 = m;

  do
  {
    c = (g1 + g2) / 2;
    diff = c * m - 1.0f;
    if (diff > 0)
      g2 = c;
    else
      g1 = c;
  } while (fabs(diff) > epsilon);

  printf("The reciprocal is approximately %f", c);
}
```

For your question "*Also is there a faster method to converge from the limits to the required value (reciprocal of the input) rather than just averaging it?*", I have no idea, but searching by bisection is generally rather fast.

Test program that tests for a range of values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

#define epsilon 0.0001f

int main(void)
{
  float g1, g2, c, diff;

  for (float m = 1; m < 20; m += 1)
  {
    g1 = epsilon;
    g2 = m;

    do
    {
      c = (g1 + g2) / 2;
      diff = c * m - 1.0f;
      if (diff > 0)
        g2 = c;
      else
        g1 = c;
    } while (fabs(diff) > epsilon);

    printf("The reciprocal of %f is approximately %f vs. %f, diff %f\n", m, c, 1/m, c-1/m);
  }
}
```

**[Live demonstration](https://www.ideone.com/j35Jmz)**

Comment: Thanks for trying! But it is only working for some numbers. For example on giving input 5, the output is 0.2, which is correct. But for input 10, it gives 5 as the output. Same goes for 8,24.

Comment: @SaumyaBhatt try now, I edited the answer. It should now work on your platform. Live demonstration: https://www.ideone.com/j35Jmz

Comment: Just one doubt, what does defining epsilon as 0.0001'f' means? What's the 'f' for? Same goes for what does '1.0f' in the formula for diff means?

Comment: @SaumyaBhatt the `f` means that it's a `float` literal and not a `double` literal. Not actually important here, you can write `0.0001` (without the `f`)