# Finding roots of an equation using Bisection

Tags: c

Am trying to find the roots of the equation (x^3)-(x^2)+2 using bisection method. For this, I took two values from the user to act as the initial guesses( called limits here) and then converge onto the value where the function goes to 0. But whenever I change the limits, the value also differ by large amounts and none of them are close to the actual value. Any suggestions where I might be wrong?

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
# define Epsilon 0.0001
float f(float x)
{
    return x*x*x-x*x+2;
}
float bisection(float a, float b)
{
    if(f(a)*f(b)>0)
    {
        printf("No root within this interval.");
    }
    float c=a;
    while(abs(b-a)>Epsilon)
    {
        c=(a+b)/2;
        if(f(a)*f(c)<0)
        {
            b=c;
        }
        else if(f(b)*f(c)<0)
        {
            a=c;
        }
        else if(f(c)==0)
        {
            printf("The root of x^3-x^2+2 is %f",c);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("The root of x^3-x^2+2 is %f",c);
}
int main(void)
{
    float u,l;
    printf("Enter upper limit:\n");
    scanf("%f",&u);
    printf("Enter lower limit:\n");
    scanf(" %f",&l);
    bisection(l,u);
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show one or two samples of input and expected output.

Comment: `f(c)==0` - this is unlikely to be true ever. Have some other `epsilon` instead.

Comment: If you look closely to the answer of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54982281/898348), you may have noticed that in the answer there is an `#include <cmath>` and that `fabs` is used instead of `abs`.

Comment: And BTW the code you posted here doesn't compile because `bisection` doesn't return a value. Probably `bisection` should be a `void bisection(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need `#include <cmath>`
2. You need to replace `abs` (integer absolute value) with `fabs` (floating point absolute value)
3. You need to check against Epsilon :  `if (f(c) <= Epsilon)` instead of `if (f(c) == 0)` which is unlikely to happen.

But anyway you still need to check if there *is* a solution. If there is no solution in the guess interval, the loop in the function never stops. This left as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop in your `bisection` function.

`if (f(a)*f(b)>0)` you determine that there is no root to be found within your interval; then you proceed to try to find it.  You fail to find a subinterval where a root exists, so you don't change anything and try again.